# Is GNU GRUB installed under a OS, or not under any OS?

Tags: bios, grub

BIOS, a boot loader, is installed not under any OS.

Is GNU GRUB, another boot loader, installed under a OS, or not under any OS?

Thanks!

Comment: BIOS isn't considered a boot loader...it's also not something you install

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BIOS is not a bootloader.  It tries to load a bootloader off of a boot device.  It does this by loading the first sector of of a device.  There is not a lot of space in a device's sector, so typically, the very tiny program in this sector will load a "second stage bootloader" that is more capable, such as the Windows boot manager or GRUB.

When a bootloader has control of the system, an OS is not running.

OSes can install bootloaders - this is done by modifying the first sector of the hard drive involved to contain the first-stage bootloader code, and then placing other files where needed or expected, according to the bootloader in question.

I'm unclear whether UEFI, BIOS's replacement, can act as a bootloader - this is typically not done with Windows systems, though.  Other firmwares for other platforms such as U-Boot can understand a couple filesystems and load a kernel off of it directly - they have bootloader capability unlike the PC platform's BIOS.

Answer (score 1):

The BIOS — the PC/AT firmware on your machine — *has* a bootloader.  It incorporates one amongst many other things.  The bootloader loads the first block off a disc device (of some sort) and runs the program that is embedded within it.  That program is either a standard MBR bootstrap program, as most operating systems install, or the first stage of a program like GRUB, installed MBR-virus-style in the second and subsequent blocks of the disc device.

Both the standard MBR bootstrap program and GRUB run directly on top of the machine firmware, making use of firmware-supplied services for I/O and suchlike.  They don't run on top of an operating system.

*Their installation programs*, the programs that write the programs into the first and subsequent sectors of the disc device, run on top of operating systems.

In the world of EFI firmware, the firmware has a boot *manager*.  It understands the FAT filesystem format, and can read executable files from FAT volumes and run them.  These executable files are often *kernel loader* programs.  Sometimes, in particular in the case of Microsoft Windows, they are *further* boot managers.  These programs also run on top of the machine firmware, making use of EFI services for I/O and suchlike, and not on top of an operating system.

### Further reading

- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2011). [*The different kinds of bootstrap programs*](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/bootstrap-programs.html).  Frequently Given Answers.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2011). [*The PC/AT boot process*](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/pcat-boot-process.html).  Frequently Given Answers.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2006). [*The EFI boot process*](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/efi-boot-process.html).  Frequently Given Answers.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2006). [*The ARC boot process*](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/arc-boot-process.html).  Frequently Given Answers.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2006). [*The Windows NT 6 boot process*](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/windows-nt-6-boot-process.html).  Frequently Given Answers.